# Display JSON - Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

is it possible to display response JSON in the blade as it is? like

> {{ $collection }}

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Quam accusantium dolore qui.",
        "description":"Ipsa mollitia et rerum sint.",
        ...
    }
]
```

I want it well-formatted like in the above to make it more readable.

Comment: view('your-view')->with('collection ', json_decode($collection , true));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use `pre tag`

```
<pre>{{ $collection }}</pre>
```

Also you can use  `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` as second `param` to `json_encode` if json is not formatted already

```
$data=json_decode('[
  {"id":1,"name":"Quam accusantium dolore qui.","description":"Ipsa mollitia et rerum sint."}
]');
     
    return view('welcome',['collection'=>json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)]);
```

and in your view

```
  <pre >
 <code style="color: #ff12a0;">{{$collection}}</code>
  </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

To view json as it is you have to use html pre tag

First encode your json data like below

```
$collection = json_decode("Peter"=>35, "Ben"=>37, "Joe"=>43);
```

In html view use like this

```
{{ $collection }}
```